# How can you move (or copy) all files of a certain type to a directory in Unix?

Tags: unix, file-transfer, file-types, stdout

I'm not very familiar with all the tricks of grep/find/awk/xargs quite yet, so be patient with me =]

I have a particular file type say *.xxx, in random places throughout a certain directory. How can I find all such files, and move them to a folder in my home directory on Unix (that may not exist yet)?

Answer (score 4):

Use `find` with the `exec` option, but first create the target folder.

```
mkdir -p /home/somewhere/else
find /somewhere -iname "*.xxx"
```

This will list everything that would be moved. Now if you're sure these are the files you want to move, execute the following:

```
find /somewhere -iname "*.xxx" -exec mv '{}' /home/somewhere/else/ \;
```

In the `exec` line, `'{}'` will be substituted with the actual file name, and it will be moved to the target. Likewise, to copy, just exchange `mv` with `cp`. The `\;` is needed to terminate the command.

If you want a confirmation before each file operation that would overwrite an already existing file, you can add the `-i` option after `mv` or `cp`, respectively.

No need for `grep`, `xargs` and their likes. This would unnecessarily complicate things.